# Building my react app using material UI. The font I have used aren't the same in Mac

Tags: css, reactjs, fonts, material-ui

The font changes in mac and iOS platforms. How to ensure the same font appears. My index.css file :

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto', 'Oxygen',
    'Ubuntu', 'Cantarell', 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica Neue',
    sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

code {
  font-family: source-code-pro, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, 'Courier New',
    monospace;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first font you specified is preferred and since it is an alias it might be different among different Apple devices. If you want it to resolve to the same font everywhere, specify one, for example "Roboto". It is recommendable to use Googles WebFontLoader to download Robot in order to avoid ugly reflows when the font is not instantly available.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the fonts from local repository and use font-face to insure that your fonts now are read from the same repository not from the device.

Download the fonts you intend to use and put them in public/Fonts directory, then in your root css add those fonts
e.g:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: local('Segoe UI'), url('SEGOE-UI.woff') format('woff');
}
{.....}
```

or/and whatever other fonts you're using